# Firefox config: How to set settings that are not visible?

Tags: firefox, configuration

I would like to set a setting (nglayout.debug.disable_xul_cache) to true. But when i enter "about:config" in my FireFox and search for this setting i cannot find it.

How can i set this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the screen in `about:config`, select `New -> Boolean` and enter your setting name (`nglayout.debug.disable_xul_cache`). Then select `true`, click `Ok` and you're done.